# Property name of a function that preserves the distribution of error term

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Suppose I have a function s.t.

$$f(x+\epsilon_{i})=f(x)+\epsilon_{j}$$

where $\epsilon_{i,j}$ both follow normal distribution with mean 0 for any $x \in \Bbb{R}$.

Is there a name for functions that has this property?

Thanks!

Comment: The only continuous fucntion $f$ with this property is $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Thanks Kavi! What if I allow ei and ej to have different variance or different means? (but they're still both normally distributed??)